# With GMail API, Is it possible to insert message to INBOX?

Tags: gmail-api

With GMail API, it is possible to `insert` a message to inbox with https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert

The problem I face is when using `insert`, messages do not appear in INBOX and user has to go to 'All Mail' in order to see them.

What is the best way to `insert` messages *into* INBOX? Import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the request body based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert):

```
Request Body: {
   "raw": "string" // required property
   "labelIds": "["INBOX"]" // add this optional property
   "threadId": "string"
}
```

Here's the complete list for [Type of Message labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels).

Comment: Yes! I was trying to apply INBOX label _after_ inserting it and it does not work, but it does when you do it as a part of the `insert` call. Thank you!